# SwiftUI - Remove padding around Picker SegmentedPickerStyle when in a Form Section

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Im trying to remove the padding around the picker as seen below, im only a few weeks into SwiftUI having come from ObjectiveC. My various attempts of setting the paddings and insets are below, any help would be great

[image]

```
var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section {
            Picker("", selection: $viewOption) {
                Text("Staff").tag("staff")
                Text("Signals").tag("signals")
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .frame(height: 40)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: -10, leading: 0, bottom: -10, trailing: 0))
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            
            }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: -20, bottom: 0, trailing: -20))
            .frame(height: 40)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        Section(header: Text("YOUR PROFILE")) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        //.clipShape(Circle())
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Andrew Webb").font(Font.system(size:20, design: .default))
                        Text("Test").font(.subheadline).fontWeight(.thin)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                Toggle(isOn: $isOnDuty) {
                    Text("On Duty")
                    
                }.onChange(of: isOnDuty) { value in
                    self.isShowingModalAlert.toggle()
                     print(value)
                }.sheet(isPresented: $isShowingModalAlert) {
                                            ModalAlertSheetView(text: $alertInput, location: $location)
                                        }
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Form`s are using grouped list style, you'll have to set the inset to zero and change the background color of the picker row:

```
        Form {
            Picker("My Picker", selection: .constant(0)) {
                ForEach(0..<3) {
                    Text(String($0))
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .listRowInsets(.init())
            .listRowBackground(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
        }
```

Comment: Great Answer, exactly what i was missing.

Comment: This didn't work but .listRowBackground(Color.clear) did.

Answer (score 0):

Just move it outside Form, like

```
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    Picker {
    }

    Form {
    }
}
```

Comment: This does work, but it then moves it out of the scrolling form view